# Unable to retrieve data and use it in a UIBarButton - Firebase Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to retrive a user's username and save it to a variable, although whenever I run the code nothing happens. This is my Firebase layout:
[image]

And here is my code which is in my `viewDidAppear()`

```
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
let ref:FIRDatabaseReference!
ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("users").child("\(uid)")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    print("test")
    if !snapshot.exists() { return }

    let user = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String ?? ""
    print(user)
    let username = UIBarButtonItem(title: user, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
    let picture = UIBarButtonItem()
    self.navigationController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = username
})
```

Comment: If you step through the code in a debugger, what happens?  Does it go into the `observeSingleEvent` callback?

Comment: The code runs, but when I try to print the username nothing comes out (print(user)) EDIT: The code runs, but the code doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().root.child("users").child("\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)")observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
   print("test")
   if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
          let user = snapDict["name"] as! String
          print(user)
          let username = UIBarButtonItem(title: user, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
          let picture = UIBarButtonItem()
          self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = username
        } else {
           print("No such user exists!.")
      }
 })
```

Comment: That's retrieving the username correctly, but it isn't displaying it on the navigation controller. Maybe I'm setting it up incorrectly?

Comment: great answer @Dravidian !